# I can not pass a string to fragment

Tags: android

call fragment from fragment. I need to pass a string to the fragment. how to do it?

```
if (position==1){
            FragmentTransaction ft;
            VideoList lf = new VideoList();
            ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragmentsPanel, lf);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
```

I want to pass String str = "absd"; and the second fragment to take String str1 = row of the first fragment

Comment: use interface as a callback to the host activity and then communicate from activity to fragment. Example in doc http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: hi checkout the my answer

Comment: ft.replace(R.id.fragmentsPanel, lf,links[position]);
 link = getTag();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arguments!

```
public static VideoList videoListWithString(String string) {

    VideoList videoList = new VideoList();
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putString("testString","test");
    videoList.setArguments(arguments);
    return videoList;

}
```

and in your fragments onCreate...

```
Bundle arguments = getArguments();
String testString = arguments.getString("testString");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use setArguments() and getArguments() methods in Fragments

like

```
if (position==1){
            FragmentTransaction ft;
            VideoList lf = new VideoList();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("str", "absd");
            ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragmentsPanel, lf);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
```

and in the fragment you get this string like this

```
public class VideoList extends ListFragment {

     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
         ViewGroup containerObject,
         Bundle savedInstanceState){
         //here is your arguments
         Bundle bundle=getArguments(); 

        //here is your list array 
        String str=bundle.getString("str");   
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("str1", "absd");
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_place, YourFragment.instantiate(getActivity(), YourFragment.class.getName(),  params), "YourFragmentTag").commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is to pass value from one fragment to another then try using bundle.

For example:

```
TalkDetail fragment = new TalkDetail();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putString("title", title);
bundle.putString("largeimg", largeimg);
bundle.putString("excert", excert);
bundle.putString("description",description);
bundle.putString("cat", cat);
bundle.putString("header_title", "Talk");
//bundle.putInt("postid", postid);

fragment.setArguments(bundle);

((BaseContainerFragment)getParentFragment()).replaceFragment(fragment, true);
```

Here's your `BaseContainerFragment` class that will help to get better back track and other good stuff

```
 public class BaseContainerFragment extends Fragment {

            public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                if (addToBackStack) {
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                }
                transaction.replace(R.id.container_framelayout, fragment);
                transaction.commit();
                getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
            }

            public boolean popFragment() {
                Log.e("test", "pop fragment: " + getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
                boolean isPop = false;
                if (getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                    isPop = true;
                    getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                }
                return isPop;
            }

        }
```